# D10 4.0-beta1: How far from production-ready?

Tags: drupal, cms-integration

I'm considering recommending, in a short timeframe, some sort of CRM that integrates as natively as possible with Drupal. Salesforce is probably overkill for our needs. CiviCRM, and most CRMs, could probably meet it, to the extent they integrate. Monday is currently in use but likely able to redirected from if appropriate. So my question is:

How ready for a production site is the current D10 version today? How big or small, how numerous are the blockers to it moving out of beta today, next month, or two months from now? What is any sort of reasonable time horizon for this shift to being fully reliable and ready? Are the remaining blocks small enough that a reasonably senior Drupal dev could erase them in short order, or are they more complicated and require CiviCRM-specific expertise? I know these questions are super broad, but that is intentionally so because it's a quick decision turnaround based on as best-informed speculation as you all can discern / suggest.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean by "4.0-beta1" but drupal 10 + civicrm is production ready. https://docs.civicrm.org/installation/en/latest/general/requirements/

And take these stats with a grain of salt but most of the sites listed here as "drupal 8" are actually drupal 10, or at least drupal 9: http://stats.civicrm.org/?tab=sites. The stats don't distinguish between 8/9/10.

In terms of additional tight integration note also there are two highly used modules:

- https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_entity (views support)
- https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm (webform)

Comment: Apologies, I realize now that the version was a reference to the CiviCRM Entity / Views support module you mentioned, not the more general CiviCRM project, although Views support is probably important for us. Thank you for the requirements link and stating it's already production-ready, which I wasn't clear on until now.

Comment: I can confirm D10 + CiviCRM is production ready - we host/maintain several dozen CiviCRM instances on D10. Also have a look at this post for your considerations regarding Views - there are different approaches to it.

Comment: Which post? I'm not seeing a link.